# Wrong canonical link on wp-admin pages

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, htaccess, site-url, rel-canonical

I have a subdomain:

```
https://blog.example.com/
```

I forcibly redirects to directory:

```
https://www.example.com/blog
```

By changing site URL and some RewriteRule on .htaccess.

My **.htaccess**:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /blog/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Host}i ^example\.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
    </IfModule>
```

My wordpress address and site address are:

**WordPress Address (URL)**: `/blog`

**Site Address (URL)**: `https://www.example.com/blog`

Now the website working fine, but I found an error in wp-admin canonical url on all admin pages:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'blog.example.com/wp-admin/index.php'; cannot be created in a document with origin 'example.com'; and URL 'example.com/blog/wp-admin/index.php';
```

When I dig more I found the canonical link is still subdomain( **blog.example.com** ) :

```
<link id="wp-admin-canonical" rel="canonical" href="http://blog.example.com/wp-admin" />
    <script>
        if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
            window.history.replaceState( null, null, document.getElementById( 'wp-admin-canonical' ).href + window.location.hash );
        }
    </script>
```

Is there any solution for changing this canonical url from **https://blog.example.com** to **https://www.example.com/blog**

Comment: Any luck I have this too when using `https` its showing `http://`

Comment: I also have a wrong wp-admin-canonical url ... did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution for this. Instead I moved my wordpress setup to amazon instance and database to RDS. Then Stop using subdomain redirection and directly pointed /blog location to the amazon instance. All good now.

Answer (score 2):

wp-admin-canonical is [broken](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35561), as it assumes how WordPress is installed.

there was a plugin to fix it, but the plugin was removed from the plugin repository apparently. It is still on github and pluginmirror though:
https://github.com/wp-plugins/remove-wp-canonical-url-admin-hack
http://www.pluginmirror.com/plugins/remove-wp-canonical-url-admin-hack/

Comment: On version wordpress version 4.8.1, it looks like this is not needed anymore, but older versions may still need this, so at least lets document it

Answer (score 1):

### Update

The code below didn't really worked for me, as it adds a correct canonical tag but I wasn't able to remove the wrong one with `remove_action`.

Also, I found that pagination and sorting links in post and page lists had the wrong URL on it as well.

So the solution has been much simpler, just add `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'www.yoursite.com';` anywhere in `wp-config.php`.

---

### Previous answer

I've overrided the `wp-admin-canonical` by adding this hooks in `functions.php`:

```
remove_action( 'admin_head', 'wp_admin_canonical_url' );
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wp_set_admin_canonical_url' );

function wp_set_admin_canonical_url() {
    $removable_query_args = wp_removable_query_args();

    if ( empty( $removable_query_args ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Ensure we're using an absolute URL.
    $current_url  = admin_url( preg_replace( '#^[^?]*/wp-admin/#i', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );
    $filtered_url = remove_query_arg( $removable_query_args, $current_url );
    ?>
    <link id="wp-admin-canonical" rel="canonical" href="<?php echo esc_url( $filtered_url ); ?>" />
    <script>
        if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
            window.history.replaceState( null, null, document.getElementById( 'wp-admin-canonical' ).href + window.location.hash );
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

I've taken the code from this pull request: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/pull/1504

Comment: thank you, it works like a charm

Comment: but it was doubling up the resulting code so i commented out add_action( 'admin_head', 'wp_admin_canonical_url' );  in wp-admin/includes/admin-filters.php

Comment: You should not edit Wordpress Core files as your changes will be overrided on the next update.